# How to find the 'distance' between two populations?

Tags: distance, distance-functions, divergence

I am somewhat new to these concepts, so please bear with me.

I have two datasets: `Data set A` is collected by monitoring the network data of a device when it is doing `Task A` and `Data set B` is collected when the device is doing `Task B`.
The same feature set is used to describe both of these datasets.

I need the feature that has the highest distance between these two sets. An example is given in the crude diagram below.

Each plot represents the values of the chosen feature.
X axis represents the index of each datapoint and y represents the value of the chosen feature.
Black line represents `Data set A` and gray line represents `Data set B`.

In this case, I would like to choose Feature 3 since it displays the largest distance between the two datasets.

**My question**: What is the best distance measurement technique I can use to measure the distance between the two data sets for each feature separately and choose the feature with the highest distance?

[image]

Comment: Possible way: mean square difference?

Comment: When the functions are densities (total integral is one), you can also use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance, i.e. the maximum didtance between the cumulative distrbution functions. Or the Cramer-vanMieses distance, i.e. the integral over the absolute difference.